# How do I get rows from a list(table) in a protractor e2e test?

Tags: html, angular, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

The list in question is a table generated by a reactive angular form which does not have a specific ID. Following code is used to generate the list in angular part:

```
<p-table id='paragraphList' *ngIf="paragraphsObs | async; else loading"
         [value]="paragraphsObs | async"
         selectionMode="single" (onRowSelect)="select($event)"
         scrollable="true">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr> ...header... </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-paragraph let-rowData>
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
      <td width="15%">{{paragraph.cell1}}</td>
      <td width="10%">{{paragraph.cell2}}</td>
      <td width="31%">{{paragraph.cell3}}</td>
      <td width="11%">{{paragraph.cell4 | dateTransform: helperService.MM_DD_YYYY_HH_MM_A_Z_DATE_PATTERN}}
      </td>
      <td width="11%">{{paragraph.cell5}}</td>
      <td width="11%">{{paragraph.cell6 | dateTransform: helperService.MM_DD_YYYY_HH_MM_A_Z_DATE_PATTERN}}
      </td>
      <td width="11%">{{paragraph.cell7}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

The corresponding table generated at the front-end has the following html source:

```
<p-table _ngcontent-c6="" id="paragraphList" scrollable="true" selectionmode="single" ng-reflect-selection-mode="single" ng-reflect-scrollable="true" class="ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-value="[object Object],[object Object">
  <div class="ui-table ui-widget ui-table-hoverable-rows" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
    <div class="ui-table-scrollable-wrapper ng-star-inserted">  
      <div class="ui-table-scrollable-view" ng-reflect-frozen="false">
        <div class="ui-table-scrollable-header ui-widget-header">...header...</div>
        <div class="ui-table-scrollable-body">
          <table class="ui-table-scrollable-body-table" ng-reflect-klass="ui-table-scrollable-body-table" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">               
            <tbody class="ui-table-tbody" ng-reflect-template="[object Object]">
              <tr _ngcontent-c6="" ng-reflect-data="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted">...</tr>
              <tr _ngcontent-c6="" ng-reflect-data="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted">...</tr>
               ...
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="ui-table-virtual-scroller"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</p-table>
```

I want to reach to those inner  elements and get them as a list. I have tried using class names with element and all locators, to get the elements but to no avail. Then I tried using tag names to reach to those elements but that too doesn't seem to work.

This following small snippet returns 0 for the count of elements that I try to obtain from the list.

```
element(by.id('paragraphList')).element(by.css('.ui-table-scrollable-body-table'))
  .all(by.tagName('tr')).count().then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you want in the list??? The rows??

Comment: Will a format like this fine for you?? An array of arrays where each array will be the contents of cells??

Comment: Yes, I want rows in the list. Any collections would do as long as I have individual rows to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering above is your full rendered HTML..
The code below will give an Array of arrays, where each array would be containing texts from all the cells of a row.

Explanation:
The code has three functions,
`populateData()` - is the driving function where we pass the resolved list of `rows`.

Then `_populateRows()` and `_populateCells()` run recursively to gather the text from the cells. This is also possible to do with a loop (as protractor queues the promises by itself) but I like keeping things clear on my end. `_populateRows()` recur on rows and `_populateCells()` recur on cells of each row. (more in comments)

**Note** This first thing which you should do before implementing this is: check the `count()` (or `.length` of `resolvedRows`) of `element.all(by.css('#paragraphList table tbody tr'))`. As basically this was your original question I believe. Now If you have a count, then you can go with this solution or whatever suites your need.

```
let allRows = element.all(by.css(`#paragraphList table tbody tr`)); //will have all the rows.
allRows.then((rowsResolved) => {
    // now have all the rows
    PO.populateData(rowsResolved).then((allData) => {console.log(allData)})  // should be an Array od arrays, each array would be containing texts from all the cells. 
    // Considering you have a Page Object and added the functions below in the Page Object.
    // Page Object is nothing but another class where we keep our utility methods
})


//    driving function
populateData(rowsResolved) {
    let data = [];
    return this._populateRows(0, rowsResolved, data);
}

// calls itself recursively to loop over the rows
private _populateRows(index, rowsResolved, data) {
    if (index >= rowsResolved.length) {
        let defer = protractor.promise.defer();
        defer.fulfill(data);
        return defer.promise;   // so that it is chainable even if I don't have any rows
    }

    let cells = element.all(by.css(`#paragraphList table tbody tr:nth-child(${index + 1}) td`));
    cells.then((cellsResolved) => {
        let cellData = [];
        if (cellsResolved.length) {
            data.push(cellData);
        }
        this._populateCells(0, cellsResolved, cellData);
        return this._populateRows(index + 1, rowsResolved, data);
    })
}

// calls itself recursively to loop over all the cells ofeach row.
private _populateCells(index, cellsResolved, cellData) {
    if (index >= cellsResolved.length) {
        let defer = protractor.promise.defer();
        defer.fulfill(cellData);
        return defer.promise;  // so that it is chainable even if I don't have any cells(that would be an incorrect structure though, if a row exists then cells have to exist )
    }

    cellsResolved[index].getText().then((cellValue) => {
        cellData.push(cellValue)
    });
    return this._populateCells(index + 1, cellsResolved, cellData);
}
```

Comment: The css selector is still not working. It gives me 0 for the row count.

Comment: @AmritanshuJoshi: In your browser, go the page you want to test in the App, open inspect elements and do: `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#paragraphList table tbody tr'))`. What do you see? If you see empty then you have not provided the exact DOM structure in the question, and actually you don't need to,  thats something you can figure out yourelf.

Comment: It's finally working. Turns out the selector was right all along but the list takes some time on page load before the test can access it. I put in a browser.wait() for the page to load properly and now I am getting the correct count and list items. I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: The list length is fine. But the code is still giving an error when I try to log all the elements. The error: **- Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined** 
is at line: `this.populateData(rowsResolved).then((allData) => {console.log(allData)})`